# How to always show up pure HTML5/CSS modal window without clicking a link which activates it?

Tags: css, html

I have a pure HTML5/CSS modal window inside Razor View `UserPanel` in ASP.NET MVC application. I can activate this modal window by clicking a link: `<p><a href="#modal" class="btn go">Activate Modal</a></p>`the problem is I want it to be displayed always when visiting `/UserPanel` page and don't have to click on this button.

The short html and then full css for the modal(it works - > the modal shows up only after clicking the button):

html:

```
<div class="container">
    <p><a href="#modal" class="btn go">Activate Modal</a></p>
</div>

<div id="modal">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="header">
            <h2>Notification</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="copy">
            <p>There is new Announcment to read!</p>
        </div>
        <div class="cf footer">
            <a href="#" class="btn">Close</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="overlay"></div>
</div>
```

css:

```
<style>
    #modal {
        left: 50%;
        margin: -250px 0 0 -40%;
        opacity: 0;
        position: absolute;
        top: -50%;
        visibility: hidden;
        width: 80%;
        box-shadow: 0 3px 7px rgba(0,0,0,.25);
        box-sizing: border-box;
        transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
        -moz-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
        -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
    }

        #modal:target {
            opacity: 1;
            top: 50%;
            visibility: visible;
        }

        #modal .header, #modal .footer {
            border-bottom: 1px solid #e7e7e7;
            border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
        }

        #modal .footer {
            border: none;
            border-top: 1px solid #e7e7e7;
            border-radius: 0 0 5px 5px;
        }

        #modal h2 {
            margin: 0;
        }

        #modal .btn {
            float: right;
        }

        #modal .copy, #modal .header, #modal .footer {
            padding: 15px;
        }

    .modal-content {
        background: #f7f7f7;
        position: relative;
        z-index: 20;
        border-radius: 5px;
    }

    #modal .copy {
        background: #fff;
    }

    #modal .overlay {
        background-color: #000;
        background: rgba(0,0,0,.5);
        height: 100%;
        left: 0;
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        width: 100%;
        z-index: 10;
    }
</style>
```

Question: How to always show modal when visiting this page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your HTML to this (we simply target the close button):

```
<div id="modal">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="header">
            <h2>Notification</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="copy">
            <p>There is new Announcment to read!</p>
        </div>
        <div class="cf footer">
            <a href="#modal" class="btn">Close</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="overlay"></div>
</div>
```

and now the CSS to this:

```
 #modal {
        left: 50%;
        margin: -250px 0 0 -40%;
        opacity: 1;
        position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        visibility: visible;
        width: 80%;
        box-shadow: 0 3px 7px rgba(0,0,0,.25);
        box-sizing: border-box;
        transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
        -moz-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
        -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
    }

        #modal:target{
            opacity: 0;
            top: -50%;
            visibility: hidden;
        }

        #modal .header, #modal .footer {
            border-bottom: 1px solid #e7e7e7;
            border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
        }

        #modal .footer {
            border: none;
            border-top: 1px solid #e7e7e7;
            border-radius: 0 0 5px 5px;
        }

        #modal h2 {
            margin: 0;
        }

        #modal .btn {
            float: right;
        }

        #modal .copy, #modal .header, #modal .footer {
            padding: 15px;
        }

    .modal-content {
        background: #f7f7f7;
        position: relative;
        z-index: 20;
        border-radius: 5px;
    }

    #modal .copy {
        background: #fff;
    }

    #modal .overlay {
        background-color: #000;
        background: rgba(0,0,0,.5);
        height: 100%;
        left: 0;
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        width: 100%;
        z-index: 10;
    }
```

we simply make the modal show by default, then hide it on click. Of course, if you want it always visible, just delete the close button. [See fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/3kw2ram6/)

Comment: Is there possibility of not losing the sliding down animation? If not sorry for bothering. Thank you it worked great.

Comment: it's still there, but the effect is a bit fast so maybe you didn't notice it. Just for reference, I changed it to 3 seconds so you can see it, just check http://jsfiddle.net/subx6ox2/

Comment: Thanks I see closing transition just didn't see coming out. I changed all of those: ` transition: all 3.4s ease-in-out;
        -moz-transition: all 3.4s ease-in-out;
        -webkit-transition: all 3.4s ease-in-out;` closing slows down but when I open page the modal does not slides down(showing up animation).

Comment: ah, you mean on load? then I don't think you can unless you use JS, but of course it wouldn't be pure CSS/HTML5

Answer (score 1):

i hope ths code will help

```
<div class="container">
```

```
<div id="modal">
 <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="header">
        <h2>Notification</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="copy">
        <p>There is new Announcment to read!</p>
    </div>
    <div class="cf footer">
        <a href="#" class="btn">Close</a>
    </div>
  </div>
<div class="overlay"></div>
```

```
        #modal {
          left: 50%;
          margin: -250px 0 0 -40%;
          opacity: 0;
          position: absolute;
          top: -50%;
          visibility: hidden;
          width: 80%;
          box-shadow: 0 3px 7px rgba(0,0,0,.25);
          box-sizing: border-box;
          transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
          -moz-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
          -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
          opacity: 1;
          top: 50%;
          visibility: visible;
```

}

```
     #modal .header, #modal .footer {
         border-bottom: 1px solid #e7e7e7;
         border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
     }

    #modal .footer {
         border: none;
         border-top: 1px solid #e7e7e7;
         border-radius: 0 0 5px 5px;
   }

    #modal h2 {
         margin: 0;
    }

    #modal .btn {
         float: right;
    }

    #modal .copy, #modal .header, #modal .footer {
         padding: 15px;
    }

   .modal-content {
        background: #f7f7f7;
        position: relative;
        z-index: 20;
       border-radius: 5px;
   }

  #modal .copy {
      background: #fff;
  }

  #modal .overlay {
      background-color: #000;
      background: rgba(0,0,0,.5);
      height: 100%;
      left: 0;
      position: fixed;
      top: 0;
      width: 100%;
      z-index: 10;
 }
```

Comment: Now it does not come off when I click close, but thank you for effort.

Comment: Oops! Sorry I didn't realise that your close button was working.